# BouncyCastle package is restored using .NET Framework version, but runs well on Linux

Tags: .net

While building an app that uses BouncyCastle (1.8.9), I'm getting the following warning:

> /code/MyProject.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'BouncyCastle 1.8.9' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

This happens on a Linux host. The app works without any issues.
I wonder:

1. How is that even possible that the package gets restored with the .NET Framework version when I run `dotnet build` on a Linux box
2. How does it even run on Linux if the .NET Framework package is included?

Comment: Unless you (or the package you use) use some Windows specific pieces of .NET Framework it actually is possible to run your app on Linux thanks to some under the hood [library redirects](https://medium.com/corrado-cavalli/hownetstandardwork-a6fdcd0adff8).

Comment: Does it mean that it's actually an underdoing of BouncyCastle in how their package metadata is done?

Comment: The metadata reflects the way they build the project - BouncyCastle is a Framework project after all. To make it fully usable in both Framework and Core (and Dotnet 5.0+)  they would need to build it as netstandard2.0 and it is possible that they are unable to get it done due to referencing code that is not included there.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely replace it by the [BouncyCastle.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.NetCore). It works like a charm for me. Assuming that the app works in Linux and it builds using the .NET Core instead of .NET Framework, which is compatible for Windows only.