# BouncyCastle deployment error: HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Tags: c#, .net-core, bouncycastle

I am using the below imports from BouncyCastle dependency in my .net core project

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
```

When i try to run in my local PC it is working fine however once i deploy it is showing

HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

If i remove the dependancies it is working fine

Thanks for any helps

Comment: What type of server are you using when you deploy?  the error usually means that the code is try to access resource on the server that app doesn't have the credential to access.  If you are on a IIS server you do not have access to the file system.  If you have files put on a network drive that you can read/write.  If you are running as a service create a service account so you have an environment.  If you are connecting to a database what credentials are you using? You may need to use Authentication.

Comment: @jdweng .. I totally agree with you . but when i tries to remove the dependancies it is working fine

Comment: Are you using a new version of BouncyCastle that works with Core?

Comment: @jdweng yes 1.8.9

Comment: Looks like 1.8.10 fixed some cypto issues.  See bottom right side of following page : https://www.bouncycastle.org/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Did you build project as Net Standard 2.0?  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811768/bouncycastle-package-is-restored-using-net-framework-version-but-runs-well-on?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng my project Currently using .net 6.0.8

Comment: I'm just reading the last comment on the link.

Comment: @jdweng i read it but didnt get any lead info to resolve the issue

Comment: When you compile what version of Net/Core is the target?  There is a target setting in VS to determine the version of Net/Core.

Comment: @jdweng it is .net core 6.0

Comment: I'm just the messenger.  The link says you need to target Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: With . NET 6 you should use BouncyCastle.NetCore (currently version 1.9.0), see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.NetCore/). This works on my local machine and also online, see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OhTjwY).

Comment: @Topaco unfortunately this solution also not worked for me

Comment: This seems to be an issue specific to your environment, as BouncyCastle actually works with .NET 6 as shown in the link. You would need to ask someone here or at another stackexchange site who knows about setting up/administering/configuring .NET6 servers/machines if BouncyCastle can't be integrated after all. Unfortunately I can't help you here as I am not familiar enough with these topics.

Comment: This is weird because I am using BountyCastle too and it is deployed on AWS using .NET 6 also. and it is working fine

Comment: where are you deploying your application @AskarcAli

Comment: @CarloLuisito our own windows server

Comment: how are you importing it to your project? do you add their DLL directly to your application or do you used the nuget package?

Comment: @CarloLuisito using nuget

Comment: can you try downloading the nuget and generate the DLL and add it manually to your application?

Comment: @AskarcAli share your startup class

Comment: Can you please include the log files in the kudo console? usually it contains the error

Comment: Make sure you are installing it for .NET Core platform not for .NET platform

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, it appears as if you still do not know the cause of the error. To checkout the error follow the following steps:

**Step 1:**

Navigate to the kudu debug console
https://youappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

**Step 2**

In the console go to `wwwroot`

Enter this in the terminal:

```
cd site/wwwroot
```

**Step 3**

Then in the terminal type:

```
dotnet yourappname.dll
```

**Step 4**

Now navigate back by clicking the three dots `...` to `/`

[image]

Step 5:

Through the GUI provided. Click `LogFiles`[image]

Step 6:

Now click on `eventlog.xml` and scroll down to the bottom of the file. There the last event log will be the latest log. You will find the error there.

This is not the answer to your question. But I believe it will be helpful for you to finally solve the error!